# how to compare one correlated value with other correlated list of values in jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Need to compare my C_Category_uuid with C_Categories_1_g1,C_Categories_2_g1...so on till C_Categories_matchNr (C_Category_uuid == C_Categories_index_g1).

when ever the match found it should return C_Categories_matchedindex_g2.

I have tried writing below code but it is not working. (in grovvy)

def C_Category; list = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("C_Categories_matchNr"))

if(C_Category_uuid == 'null') {vars.put("C_Category", '""')} else{for(int i = 1; i < list; i++) {if(C_Category_uuid == 'vars.get("C_Categories_" + index + "g1")') {vars.put("C_Category", vars.get("C_Categories" + index + "g2"))}}} tried option 2: 1.upto(vars.get('C_Categories_matchNr') as int, { index -> {if(C_Category_uuid.equals(vars.get('C_Categories' + index + "g1"))) {vars.put("C_Category", 'vars.get('C_Categories' + index + "_g2")')}}});

Can any one help me in it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your "requirements" your "code" needs to be fixed to look like:

```
if (C_Category_uuid == null) {
    vars.put("C_Category", '')
} else {
    for (int i = 1; i < list; i++) {
        if (C_Category_uuid == vars.get("C_Categories_" + i + "g1")) {
            vars.put("C_Category", vars.get("C_Categories" + i + "g2"))
        }
    }
}
```

Going forward be informed that your "not working" statement doesn't tell a lot to us, it would be much better if you provide:

1. [Properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code
2. JMeter Variables values (can be obtained using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter))
3. [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file, or at least its part containing the error related to your "code"

Comment: def C_Category;
list = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("C_Categories_matchNr"))

if(C_Category_uuid == 'null')
{
 vars.put("C_Category", '""')
}
else
{
 for(int i = 1; i < list; i++)
 {
  if(C_Category_uuid == 'vars.get("C_Categories_" + index + "_g1")')
  {
   vars.put("C_Category", vars.get("C_Categories_" + index + "_g2"))
  }
 }
}
if part is working fine, whereas else part is not working (not able to see the variable in debug sampler)

Comment: 2023-12-12 15:56:10,688 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: C_Category_uuid: null
C_Category=""
2023-12-12 15:56:10,724 INFO o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: C_Category_uuid: "da1acf22-5f46-4ef5-9243-46b11d20bdd8"
Not able get C_category variable in debug sampler